# I am trying to create a chart like a sequence diagram which would show me multiple flights' landing predicted and actual time i form of line chart

Tags: google-visualization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaFwP.png)

I need three items in yaxis : scheduled, predicted, and status.
The xaxis will be time interval.
Each dot on scheduled axis is a specific flight which needs to be plotted to predicted axis and need to mention its status in status in status axis.
I am quite new to front end, and need some help in capturing the requirement

Comment: Please share some code to assists you on same !

Comment: Sorry Firu, but I am not sure where to even start. I am flexible with assuming the data. 
Though, I think it should be like : 
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ ['Flight', 'Predicted', 'Scheduled', 'Status'], ['MI225', '12:05', '12:30', 'LND'], ['KE643', '12:33', '12:14', 'APP']]); 
But, I would be getting error : Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Comment: you may only use strings on the x-axis (first column), unless it is a role such as annotation or tooltip, a valid row would be --> `['MI225', 12:05, 12:30]` -- or -- `[ ['Flight', 'Predicted', 'Scheduled', {role: 'annotation', id: 'Status'}], ['MI225', 12:05, 12:30, 'LND']`